# Pyspark: Grouping on a key in JSON and find mean of another key

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a JSON file structured like so:

```
{"time":3,"points":6}
{"time":3,"points":2}
{"time":5,"points":1}
```

Using pyspark I am attempting to group by time and then find the mean of the points to return:

```
[(3, 4),
(5, 1)]
```

The setup is:

```
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

dataset_json = sc.textFile("datafile.json")
dataset = dataset_json.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
```

And so far I can group by time, but never can get the mean of the points.

```
def points_by_hour(dataset):
    return dataset.groupBy(lambda x: x['time']).mapValues(lambda x: x['points']).mean()
```

The grouping part works as expected but I can't get it to return the mean part. The above function fails and I've tried a few iterations. Don't find the error messages helpful.

The real data file is much larger, with more keys, hence pyspark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.agg.html) function available for dataframes:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.json("datafile.json")
df = df.groupBy('time').agg(F.avg(F.col('points')).alias('avgPoints'))
df.show()


+----+---------+                                                                
|time|avgPoints|
+----+---------+
|   3|      4.0|
|   5|      1.0|
+----+---------+
```

Note that if you wanted to you can convert the dataframe to an rdd and continue:

```py
rdd = df.rdd
print(rdd.collect())

# [Row(time=3, avgPoints=4.0), Row(time=5, avgPoints=1.0)]
```

---

But here is a solution using rdd only:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
import json

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
dataset_json = sc.textFile("datafile.json")
dataset = dataset_json.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))

def points_by_hour(dataset):
    return dataset.map(lambda x: (x['time'], (x['points'], 1))) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda acc, val: (acc[0] + val[0], acc[1] + val[1])) \
        .map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0]/x[1][1]))

print(points_by_hour(dataset).collect())

# [(3, 4.0), (5, 1.0)]
```

Explanation: Initialize a count of `1` with `map`, then sum up the points and count value with `reduceByKey`, then calculate the average using `sum/count` with a final `map`.

Comment: This does work, but sort of side steps the problem. Im trying to keep it in the RDD framework.

Comment: @David2020 it's a bit trickier using rdd only, I have updated my answer with that approach too. Although if possible, consider using dataframes as they can be more convenient and you can, of course, switch between the two.

Comment: I found a simpler solution with `.map` and then `.reduceByKey(` (posted above/below).
I didn't fully understand how `reduceByKey` worked before.

I agree using DF is more convenient and translates better from pandas docs. , I was constrained in this instance. Thank for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Searching further, I found reduceByKey is more appropriate here.

```
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

dataset_json = sc.textFile("datafile.json")
dataset = dataset_json.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))

def points_by_hour(dataset):
    return dataset.map(lambda x: (x['time'], x['points'])).reduceByKey(
    lambda a, b: (a + b)/2)

points_by_hour(dataset).collect()

#[(3, 4.0), (5, 1)]
```

The average of any two numbers is their sum, divided by 2, resulting in the simple lambda function.

Comment: Note that this only works if you have 2 or less `points` per `time`. If there are more than 2 points, it will give misleading results. For example: if `time=3` has 3 separate entries of `points=6, 2, 19` it will return a result of `((6+2)/2 + 19)/2) = 11.5` instead of `9`.

Comment: Yea true. In this instance it suits, but I agree this would be a judgement call based on the structure of the data.